# Unclear proof of a proposition on semisimple rings in Lang

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I've been reading through Lang's Algebra chapter about semisimple modules and semisimple rings, and after Lang proves a main structure theorem about semisimple rings he proves the following proposition:

> Let $k$ be a field and $E$ a finite $k$-vector space.
>   Let $R$ be a $k$-subalgebra of $\operatorname{End}_k E$.
>
> Then $R$ is semisimple if and only if $E$ is semisimple as an $R$-module.

Proof goes like this:

> If $R$ is semisimple, every $R$-module is semisimple, including $E$.
>   Conversely, if $E$ is a semisimple $R$-module, then it looks like a
>   finite direct sum of simple $R$-modules:
>   $$ E = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n E_i$$
>
> For each $i$ there exists $v_i \in E_i$ such that $R.v_i = E_i$.
>   The map
>   $$ r \to (r.v_1, \ldots, r.v_n)$$
>   is a $R$-homomorphism from $R$ into $E$, **and is an injection since $R$ is contained in $\operatorname{End}_k E$**.
>   Then, $R$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $E$. The result follows from the fact that a submodule of a semisimple submodule is again semisimple.

I get everything except the bold part. Can someone explain that part to me?

Comment: This can't be right. Consider $R=\operatorname{End}_k(E)$, so that $E$ is certainly a semisimple $R$-module.  Then $R$ cannot inject into $E$ purely for dimension reasons. Probably the aim is to inject $R$ into $E^{\oplus\dim E}$